# Why does dlib.shape_predictor return different results on Ubuntu, Debian and Windows?

Tags: python, cross-platform, dlib

What may cause `dlib.shape_predictor` to return different results for the same input in Ubuntu, Debian and Windows when used in Python?
I can't  explore the data but   outer eyes and bottom lip for the same image
in debian   [[ 115.,  192.],[ 171.,  192.],[ 146.,  302.]] 
in windows [[ 115.,  192.],[ 171.,  192.],[ 147.,  301.]] 
whole  squared distance windows from debian  for 68 points  equals 64
and max difference between points 2 pixel.

Comment: Does it return the same results when you run it multiple times on the same machine?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the output differences for a given input?

Comment: Yes the result is stable for each machine